# How to write part of output content into a file in python?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write part of output from a device to file in python.
Here is my output content from the device that is stored in a `activity` as string.

```
927            turu            ery7                 berk Sun Oct 11 14:26:14.892 2020 UTC how did mark make it  
936            fh@df           ery0                 berk Sun Oct 11 14:26:43.807 2020 UTC make world more peaceful 
944            hgk3            ery8                 berk Sun Oct 11 14:28:48.385 2020 UTC mpdlf lsdi wewl ok 
949            sjff            ery9                 berk Sun Oct 11 14:31:10.820 2020 UTC no fpp ido sce
```

I want to write all the contents after UTC  in the file.
The file content should look like

```
how did mark make it  
make world more peaceful 
mpdlf lsdi wewl ok 
no fpp ido sce
```

Comment: "I'm trying" - we can't see what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.split(substring)` method on a string to turn the string into a list split by a substring. It sounds like you want to split by the substring `"UTC"` here. After splitting the string, you can write that to a file the same way you would a regular string.

e.g.

```py
myString = "berk Sun Oct 11 14:26:14.892 2020 UTC how did mark make it"
justAfterUTC = myString.split("UTC")[-1] # This is "how did mark make it"
```

You final code might look something like the following:

```py
with open("output.txt", "a+") as f:
    for line in data.split("\n"):
        f.write(line.split("UTC")[-1])
```